# Difference between Schoenfeld global test and covariate specific Schoenfeld Individual test in R

Tags: p-value, survival, residuals, schoenfeld-residuals

In R package 'survival', I am not able to understand the difference between 
Global Schoenfeld test and Individual Schoenfeld test and teh corresponding p-values. 
I have clinical data with three attributes: Survival , Death and Category. Category contains 3 values (1,2 and 3) and I have to plot the Schoenfeld residual plots for each category. 
My code is as follows:

```
library(survival)
fit <- coxph(Surv(Survival, Death) ~ Category, data=Data)
cox.zph.fit <- cox.zph(fit)
# plot all variables
ggcoxzph(cox.zph.fit)
```

The output plots contain Individual p values and there is also a global p value. Could someone explain the difference between the two and how to interpret them?

Now I want three Schoenfeld residual plots for each category value. Since there are 3 category values, so there will be 2 plots (with one category value taken as reference).